# Remove special characters from a string in oracle apex

Tags: oracle-apex

I have an item having value as :P1_CODE = 'AAAA-BB-CC-123'

From the above i just want AAAABBCC123 (Need to remove the special character)

Comment: Is there anything special about your question that makes it specific to APEX, like the situation @cengiz sevimli mentioned below? Or do you just need to strip non-alphanumeric characters from a string, where REPLACE or REGEXP_REPLACE would do the job?

Answer (score 1):

If "special character" is a minus sign, just replace it:

```
SQL> select replace('AAAA-BB-CC-123','-') from dual;

REPLACE('AA
-----------
AAAABBCC123

SQL>
```

---

If it is something else, then: what characters do you consider "special"? Or, maybe it is simpler to ask which characters are "valid" (and should be left in the result)?

Answer (score 0):

If your page item is an interactive one (meaning user can enter values) you can consider having a [validation.](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/apex/22.2/htmdb/understanding-validations.html)

If it is just to display the value you have in a database table, you can use [format masks.](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/apex/22.2/htmdb/applying-format-masks-to-items.html)